# Discord.js target, cache user id

Tags: discord.js

I want the bot to cache the user id, this is what I got

```
    let target = message.mentions.users.first() || ??? || message.author;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

Comment: Just a warning - this returns an instance of `GuildMember` while the others return a `User`. You may want to change this to `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])?.user` to get a `User` or the others to `message.mentions.members.first()` and `message.member` for `GuildMember`s